# Styling a radio button

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, radio-button

I have a jQuery dialog on two different pages. For some reason the radio buttons look different (one page is pure HTML/Javascript and the other is created by some internal framework created by the customer I'm working for).

I'm trying to figure out what to look for in the css that causes the difference in radio button presentation.

The two scenarios look like this:

#### Wrong:

[image]

#### Right:

[image]

Can anyone help with some clues as to what to look for?

Maybe I should add that both pictures are from IE8.

Comment: Well first step is always to check the generated DOM and compare the two version. If the equal, then you would check the styles that are applied to the correct and incorrect one and compare these. Probably there is just a stylesheet missing, or one rule overwrites another.

Comment: No idea about IE8, but decent browsers provide an "Inspect element" context menu where you can see the CSS applied to the element you right click on. However, you're probably supposed to provide certain markup with certain class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit:

```
<meta name="MSThemeCompatible" content="no">
```

This bit is in one page and not the other. So either I have to remove it in one page or add it to the other to make them look alike.

Answer (score 9):

Styling *(EDIT: borders, colors, background of)* a radio button itself is not possible in css. But you can hack a bit around with hidden radio buttons and overlaid images like described here

- http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
- http://www.andreapinchi.it/how-to-style-radio-buttons-with-pure-css/

Essentially you *hide your radio button* and put a `span` right at its place that, when clicked, changes its styling:

**html**

```html
<label><input type="radio"><span class="overlay"></span> radio button</label>
```

**css**

```css
input[type=radio] {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
/* default radio button style: unchecked */
.overlay {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -1em; /* or whatever length you need here */
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}
/* changed style when checked */
input[type=radio]:checked + .overlay {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Try it in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJeKK/)

Comment: -1 for "styling a radio button itself is impossible with CSS". First of all, the article you link to shows how to do it with CSS (and so invalidates your statement), second, it is rather achieveavle, and third, I have done it. With CSS. P.S. "-1" is symbolic, I won't take away from you useful answer.

Comment: What I meant is that you can't change the `background` or `border` of a radio button: http://jsfiddle.net/ABQSv/. (If you can, I was totally wrong and admit everything. But show me.) You sure *can* style a radio button with pure css (like its position, opacity, whatever), but I think this was not how it was meant.

Comment: Did some cross-browser checks, indeed it does work in (pre-blink) Opera and Internet explorer. Shame on me. (But not working in Firefox/Webkit is a major concern I think...)

Comment: I think I found something going through loads of css files: A CSS filter definition. I hope removing this will help. Just waiting for the site to be redeployed.

Comment: Well... removing the filter made my text look better but the actual radio button is still displayed in two different ways.

Comment: @Dominik Schreiber, you can change *both* the background and the border of a radio button, and pretty much any other form control. You need to apply the `-webkit-appearance: none` rule first though, which gets rid of all visual style of the control. And of course this only works in Webkit browsers. Other browsers may have their own vendor specific `appearance` CSS extension.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect both elements with Web Developer Tool. Press F12 in IE8 then click on the cursor icon top left (or press Ctrl+B). Click on the radio button to inspect it.

It is recommended use Google Chrome's WDT, 'cause it can tell you more (eg. related CSS file) plus easier and faster to use. You can right click on the radio button and click 'Inspect Element' to see more (DOM, CSS).

Comment: FF (latest) also has this functionality integrated (no firebug required anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Styling of radio buttons is very limited, especially in older browsers. I wrote a tutorial about how to customize checkboxes and radios with CSS only, as well as create on/off switches via styling the label and using it's `:before` and `:after` pseudoclasses. It has an IE8 fallback. Maybe this helps :) Read it here: http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/custom-inputs